# Java String index with "\n"

Tags: java, string, indexof

with this String:

```
String test = "hey\nyo\nsup\nyello";
```

and I call

```
System.out.println(test.indexOf("yello"));
```

I get 11, how is that number produced? and does "\n" count as a character in the String?

Answer (score 7):

**does "\n" count as a character in the String?**

Yes, in java `\n` is treated as a single character

```
h e y \n y o \n s u p \n yello
-------------------------------
0 1 2  3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Thats why you got `11` for `test.indexOf("yello")`

---

You can try this as a proof:

```
String str = "\n";
System.out.println(str.length());
```

will give you `1` as the output

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
"hey\nyo\nsup\nyello"
 0 0  0  0 0  1 1 1    (x)
 0 2  4  6 8  0 2 4    (y)
```

Where each char index in the string is (10x+y).

As you can see y is at position 11 (and yes `\n` is one char)

Comment: What do the numbers in the first row mean?... please eleborate (i'll upvote).

Comment: @ambigram_maker up and down number combination is position of character. E.g. 00=0, 04=4, 10=10

Comment: The numbers represent the offset of each character in the string. It's hard to read because you have to read it downward, so to speak. RC wrote it this way because it allows expressing multiple-digit offsets beneath the correct characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `\n` is treated as a single character in Java.

The numbers are produced as:

```
"hey\nyo\nsup\nyello"
 0 0  0  0 0  1 1 1 
 0 2  4  6 8  0 2 4
```

which shows that `y` is at position `11`. The numbers represent the offset of each character in the string.